# Change rss page on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Recently I moved my blog from blogger to wordpress.
I want to keep my old rss feed link www.domain.com/feed/posts/default

Can I redirect 
www.domain.com/feed/posts/default 
to 
www.domain.com/rss?

PS. Similar questions assume that my domain was www.domain.blogspot.com. But i had my own domain so I can't configure the redirection from blogger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by editing your htaccess file

```
redirect 301 /feed/posts/default/ /rss/
```

[See this page](http://www.htaccessredirect.co.uk/) for some more information on redirects - I'm not sure what you mean with your second question, but the information here should help, together with a Google search of htaccess redirects.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying RewriteRule without any luck.